# What can cause jQuery selector to fail after document.ready when it works from console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, document-ready

I use jQuery to select an (unique) ID from the DOM :

```
$(document).ready(
    alert("length :" +$("#btn").length)
);
```

The alert triggers when the page is still white (I don't know if it changes anything) and, nothing is selected (len is 0).

When I copy/paste the alert in the console, when the site is "visually" ready, the alert gives "length :1" as result.

for some reasons, either document.ready or the selector does not work.

I use jQuery 3.2.1.

The button itself is like that:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">abc</a></li>
    <li><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn">said button</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have to pass an anonymous function or named function (callback) inside a ready for it to work properly i.e. after the DOM load is completed.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             //----^^^^^^^----------- here
   alert("length :" +$("#btn").length)
});
```

or the shorthand code (like every good developer out there uses)):

```
$(function(){
   alert("length :" +$("#btn").length)
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       alert("length :" +$("#btn").length)
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">abc</a></li>
    <li><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn">said button</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: (it works) If i get it right, the len is calculated too early ?

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume Sorry didn't get you. Can you elaborate. Is it not working still?

Comment: Haha, it was indeed the anonymous function missing, now it works. If i understand properly, if length was 0 it was because the length was calculated too early ? I gotta wait 8 minutes before validating an answer. BTW, the snippet uses the wrong jquery version.

Comment: Ya. doument.ready makes sure the DOM is loaded before calling the function. function inside ready will only run once the page DOM is ready for JavaScript code to execute. In your case, since the function was missing it executes before the DOM loads hence the length is 0. Also, document.ready was introduce in the early stage of jquery so it should work in any version as far as I know. :)